# Drawing in Blender

Tags: animation, import, image

I'm a completely new blender user (just finished the beginer tutorials) and basically it's my first attempt in the world of CG creation and animation.

One of my first goals is to create some 2D sprite animations using Blender's animation tools. I can draw these sprites in another software (like Gimp) and afterwards import them in Blender for animating. But this method is not so flexible because if i want to change a sprite i'll need to go back n forth from Blender to Gimp to achieve the best result.

So the question is about the drawing capabilities of Blender meaning does it have an integrated package of tools to draw in 2D like PS or Gimp? Can i draw vector, raster or both?

Also is there a drawing software that is compatible with Blender so when you change a sprite in that particular 2d drawing software to automatically change it in Blender when imported?

Sorry if the questions sound dumb. Just seeking some guidance & flexibility concerning this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Blender. :) Wiki is a nice place for newbies to learn more about it, such as [Texture Painting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Painting). The painting system was much [improved since 2.67](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Paint_System). FYI

Comment: I'm under the impression that you want to (ab)use blender to create some kind of a flip-book. Don't you wan't to create 3D models and create all 2D sprites from them? This would be IMHO the way to go.

Comment: Hi stacker I agree with you. I realize that I'm in the wrong approach. It will be more flexible and more creative to create the character in 3d, animate it and then export image sequences to simulate the 2d animations. A very big advantage against using a 2d animation software is that once you animate it in 3d you can display and export the animation at any perspective in 2d. Thanks for waking me up :)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at inkscape

Comment: Note that while you can't *draw* in vector, you can use curves to to create vector images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw bitmaps in Blender, but for your workflow, I advice against it. You still need to save your image. Gimp has much better editing tools for images. Also, it is very easy to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to export the image in Gimp, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to Blender and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reload the saved image in Blender.

That said, Blender has some features that are very good for some purposes. For instance, the texture stencil painting is awesome.

To edit images in Blender:

Open the *UV / Image Editor*. Hit *New* button. Input image dimensions. Switch to *Edit Mode* (see screenshow below). Select tool in the toolbar.

[image: Editing images with paint brushes]

Comment: Thank's for the educative answer. I admit it's a bit abnormal to expect blender to even have drawing tools for 2d sprites. I think what it offers is more than enough for a 3D package.

Comment: Just one last thing. I found this link: https://sites.google.com/site/pointatstuffweb/external-paint-autorefresh which is an add on for auto refreshing  texture paintings imported to blender from gimp/ps and vice versa.